# Favorite Vintage Life Photo's / Favorite Vintage Life's Photos

Tags: sentence-construction, usage, possessives

I have a title that I need help with. I have a community on G+ called **The Vintage Life** where members show photographs of the past. I created a collection of my favorite pictures from there, and called it 
**Favorite Vintage Life Photo's**. The caption under the title tells everyone that these are pictures from The Vintage Life Community.

My problem is, I could have thought incorrectly that 's after photo meant the collection of pictures belong to the community, possessive. Please tell me if this is correct or not, and how best to state this title.

Comment: Do it simple, "**The Vintage Life Gallery**" or something like this "*My favs from The Vintage Life community*"

Comment: My Favorite Photos from The Vintage Life

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, neither of your proposed titles works correctly. "Favorite Vintage Life Photo's" leaves the possessive hanging: there is nothing for the photos to possess. And "Favorite Vintage Life's Photos" implies that the organization is called Favorite Vintage Life.

What you want is to use *attributive nouns* properly. Nouns used attributively qualify something about the following noun, a lot like an adjective, and can be more free-form rather than being limited to possession. Here, you're already using an attributive noun phrase *almost* correctly: "Vintage Life" can qualify "Photos" to mean "photos that are *of* Vintage Life in some sense". So you can just drop the apostrophe and you're fine. ("Favorite" continues to describe the entire following phrase, "Vintage Life Photos", so the title as a whole refers only to the photos that are of or from or by Vintage Life that are also favorites.)

Alternatively, you can rephrase to use possessives. In this case, you need to rearrange "favorite" so it qualifies the right words. It's not *Vintage Life* that's the favorite here, but *Photos*. So "Vintage Life's Favorite Photos" does the job just fine. It does have the quirk that, rather than describing *your* favorite photos from Vintage Life, it appears to describe *the favorites that Vintage Life has selected for itself*, which may or may not be the impression you want to give.